# Importing types from outside the root dir

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, monorepo

I have a problem with using a shared folder between app and server which are in a single repository. My project structure is like below:

```
- project
-- app
--- src
--- package.json
--- tsconfig.json
-- shared //this folder should be accessible in backend and app
-- lib //backend
-- package.json //backend
-- tsconfig.json //backend
```

Can someone tell me why I can't use inside app components my types placed in shared? Right now when I try to import like this:

```
import { Test } from "../../shared/test.interface";
```

compiler throw me this error:

```
File '.../shared/test.interface.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '.../app'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

When i try to import this file inside lib (backend) then everything is ok. How can i properly configure app to have availability to import types from shared inside app?

here is my tsconfig.json for app

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "outDir": "src/dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try to update the "rootDir" setting in your tsconfig.json file for the app to point to the root of your project